# Can I use a generic Repository for all children of a MappedSuperClass with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mappedsuperclass

Given the following class structure:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Animal  {}

@Entity
public class Dog {}

@Entity
public class Cat {}
```

With **Spring Data JPA**, is it possible to use a generic `Animal` Repository to persist an `Animal` at runtime without knowing which kind of `Animal` it is?

I know I can do it using a Repository-per-entity and by using `instanceof` like this:

```
if (thisAnimal instanceof Dog) 
    dogRepository.save(thisAnimal);
else if (thisAnimal instanceof Cat)
    catRepository.save(thisAnimal);
}
```

but I don't want to resort to the bad practice of using `instanceof`.

I've tried using a generic Repository like this:

```
public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<Animal, Long> {}
```

But this results in this Exception: `Not an managed type: class Animal`.  I'm guessing because `Animal` is not an `Entity`, it's a `MappedSuperclass`.

What's the best solution?

BTW - `Animal` is listed with the rest off my classes in `persistence.xml`, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually the problem is with your mapping. You either use `@MappedSuperclass` **or** `@Inheritance`. Both together don't make sense. Change your entity to:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Animal  {}
```

Don't worry, the underlying database scheme is the same. Now one, general `AnimalRepository` will work. Hibernate will do the introspection and find out which table to use for an actual subtype.

Comment: Should `Animal` be listed as a class in my persistence unit in `persistence.xml`? Your suggested changed is causing a new exception: `Unable to build EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: @CFL_Jeff: typically I rely only on annotations, so I'm not sure. Can you publish full stack trace somewhere, including `Caused by`?

Comment: It seems as though I have other problems in addition to this one.  I believe you have helped me solve the issue at hand, and I will work on the new problems.  Thanks!

Comment: @CFL_Jeff: please post link to follow-up questions if you have any.