# Spring Data repository with generic as an entity type

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to use Spring Data JPA repositories in my project. Usually I create my own repository, let's say

```
interface ProductRepository extends JPARepository<Product, Long>
```

However, I want to serve a bit more complex case that fits the following:

1. I have a basic entity with common definition:

   > ```
   > @MappedSuperclass
   > public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity {
   >     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   >     @Id
   >     @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
   >     private Long id;
   >     ...
   > }
   > ```
2. I have all other entities extending the above one, for example:

   > ```
   > @Entity
   > @Table(name = "bread")
   > public class Bread extends AbstractBaseEntity {
   > @Column
   > String type;
   > ...
   > }
   > ```

and

> ```
> @Entity
> @Table(name = "butter")
> public class Butter extends AbstractBaseEntity {
> @Column
> String weight;
> ...
> }
> ```

3. I want that any repository that anyone creates, will only work with entities extending the AbstractBaseEntity. So I want to do something like this:

> `public interface MyBaseRepository<T>  extends
>   JpaRepository<T extends AbstractBaseEntity, Long>`

Then define a couple of common methods and then use it as follows:

> `public interface BreadRepository <Bread, Long> extends MyBaseRepository`

or

> public interface ButterRepository  extends MyBaseRepository

The problem is that I cannot do this.
When I define MyBaseRepository, if I use:

> `MyBaseRepository<T extends AbstractBaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>`

I have an error  that "entity does not have property type" when I running real query.
If I use just

> extends JpaRepository

I get an error that Object is not mapped.
And if I try

> `JpaRepository<T extends AbstractBaseEntity , Long>`

it just fails with unexpected binding error.

Do I miss anything or it is just not doable with Spring Data JPA?

Thanks!

Comment: See [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237664/use-abstract-super-class-as-parameter-to-spring-data-repository/25241995#25241995)

Comment: @Inheritence does not make sence in my case, looks like it is not possible. Thank you very much for answering so fast!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I had the same kind of error trying to define a repository like your `MyBaseRepository<T extends AbstractBaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>`.

In my case the error was :

> Failed to create query for method public abstract MyBaseRepository.someMethod(); Not an entity: AbstractBaseEntity

The point was that JPA was trying to implements all interfaces that extends `JpaRepository` and can't do it on `MyBaseRepository<T>` since `<T>` isn't a concrete class and `AbstractBaseEntity` not an `@Entity`.

The solution was to annotate `MyBaseRepository<T>` with `@NoRepositoryBean` to prevent JPA trying to implements this repository. And so, only your `BreadRepository` will be implemented.