# Way to dynamic modify entity in Spring data @Query

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("update RssFeedEntry feedEntry set feedEntry.read =:isRead where     feedEntry.id =:entryId")
void markEntryAsRead(@Param("entryId") Long rssFeedEntryId, @Param("isRead") boolean isRead);
```

For example I have a lot of similar entity :  RssFeedEntry ... OtherFeedEntry All of them has feedEntry.read and feedEntry.id fields (for exaple described in separate @MappedSuperclass abstract class) but mapped to different tables. So on to perform update I have to write  similar method for every entity with

```
update <AnyOfFeedEntryr> feedEntry set feedEntry.read =:isRead where     feedEntry.id =:entryId
```

Is it any way to avoid  copy past for every entity?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237664/use-abstract-super-class-as-parameter-to-spring-data-repository

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that in object oriented languages easily. For example, in Spring data as you probably use there is an interface called [Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html) and an interface called [CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) which implements Repository, and an interface called [PagingAndSortingRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html).

For example if you use CrudRepository you can use CRUD operations without having to write a single line of code.

Just like that, you can extend Repository, CrudRepository or any other interface you are using and add your own method, in your case **markEntryAsRead**, and use this interface in your actual service like `MyService extends MyCustomRepository`

Here is an implementation example you can use in your app: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations