# How to return all database columns with CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}

//this is of course invalid
List<Map<String, String>> persons = repository.findAll(Pageable p, Sortable s);
```

I want to benefit from the `CurdRepository` methods that make use of eg `Pageable`, `Sortable` or `Predicate`.
Though I'd like not to define my full `@Entity` object beforehand to fetch all desired columns, but my goal is just to fetch **any** columns present in that table of persons.

So to say: a generic *SELECT* using the jpa entity.

Is that possible?

Comment: So you basically want a `Select * from Person` without defining a `Person` class with the proper mapping to all columns?

Comment: Shortly, ```On the other hand, if you do use table inheritance, then you can use the abstract type.```

See 
[Use abstract super class as parameter to Spring data repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25237664/10345277/)

Comment: You want to use JPA but not define Entities? So why don't you use SQL?