# How to avoid hibernate from creating object of abstract class when using findAll() method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, polymorphism

I have abstract class Employee, and 3 concrete class that extends from employee.
Classes who extends from `Employee` for example `OfficeEmployee` are currently empty and also represents table in db. Only purpose of these concrete classes is to have fk reference to `Employee`. For example if `OfficeEmployee` is created, a data will be saved in `Employee` entity and only id will be saved in `OfficeEmployee` entity.

This is my Employee class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private int employeeId;

@Column(name = "employee_name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "reason_for_deactivation", length = 255)
private String reasonForDeactivation = "";

@Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false)
private Boolean isDeleted = Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

I have managed to write methods for saving,updating and deleting specific employee, but when i want to fetch all Employees i can't do that because hibernate in background is trying to create object from Employee class and i get error because that class is abstract.

This is method for getting all Employees:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl {

@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

  public List<Employee> findAll() {
    return employeeRepository.findAll();

 }
}
```

How can i solve this problem? I am open for any advice including changing my architecture.

Comment: Do you have the @DiscriminatorColumn? You need that so hibernate can instanciate the correct subclass.

Comment: I assume you haven't found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237664/use-abstract-super-class-as-parameter-for-spring-data-repository yet, please read up on it and see if it answers your question

Comment: @MartinFrey I was trying to avoid adding new column in Employee, but i don't have a choice at this point. Thank's  though

Comment: If it‘s just about referencing an employee with an office, and other references without additional attributes you can make employee a concrete class and use manytomany properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add `@DiscriminatorColumn` on `Employee` entity and `@DiscriminatorValue` on concrete classes. So now it looks like this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "employee_type") // This is added
@Data
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private int employeeId;

@Column(name = "employee_name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "reason_for_deactivation", length = 255)
private String reasonForDeactivation = "";

@Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false)
private Boolean isDeleted = Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

And concrete class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@DiscriminatorValue("Office_Employee")  // This is added
public class OfficeEmployee extends Employee{

}
```

Basically it will add new column in Employee entity called `employee_type` and based on that will have information on type of each employee, therefore i can now fetch all Employees.